# How to update API with existing Clients?

Tags: c#, api, wsdl

I have an API (wsdl), which is accessed by several Applications. I now have to add something to it, but I am not sure how to do it without updating all the other Apps.

I am writing a new App and for this I have to change several methods and add some new ones in the API. And yes, I also have to change method parameterlists.
How can I now update this API without updating the existing Apps? And no, something like Versioning does not exist. It´s one huge File.

Comment: I don't believe there is a way around it sorry. But the issue you are having has been solved with the use of Microservices and Micro Service Architectures.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially through extension methods or maybe even overloading or overriding the methods?

Another idea might to be modifying the pre-existing methods by adding optional parameters that default to null while working the API into something that's usable/versionable